# How to handle missing SingleLogout endpoint in SAML metadata?

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am using Spring SAML integration. I am getting below error when I tried to SAML logout without SingleLogout point.

I override the SAML method to check metadata has any SingleLogout point or not but it's not working.

```
Caused by: org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: IDP doesn't contain any SingleLogout endpoints
        at org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil.getLogoutBinding(SAMLUtil.java:108)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl.sendLogoutRequest(SingleLogoutProfileImpl.java:66)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter.processLogout(SAMLLogoutFilter.java:140)
```

Comment: What's your IDP?

Answer (score 0):

To properly override the lack of single logout endpoint in the metadata, you'd have to provide your own implementation of `org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfile` and inject it as a dependency in your application config. Certainly doable but quite a bit of effort for a problem that has a simpler solution: manually modify the metadata you received from the IdP and add the endpoint. (If the metadata is signed, you'll need to remove the signature).

Comment: How I can modify the metadata which I received from the IdP?

Comment: @SumitRathi It's an XML document, you can save it as a file and edit it in any text editor. Here's a good doc that describes the format: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/CONCEPT/MetadataForIdP